# Responsive Font Size - Works on Desktop but not on Device

Tags: responsive-design, font-size

For example, I have a div-block with a width equals 100% when the screen width is below 400px. Now I use response device mode in Firefox and choose a font size for my example text "Hello World" that  my text is as large as possible but still fits into my div-block.

However, as soon as I open the website with the selected font size on my phone, the text is too large and no longer fits in the the div-block. I also use the line:

I use as font size type pt.

I thought I would get the same result on my phone. Why does this problem occur? Do I also have to use pixel-density?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `<fit-text>` Web Component, see: https://fit-text.github.io

```html
<script src="https://fit-text.github.io/element.js"></script>

<fit-text>Hello Cool Web Component World!</fit-text>
```